# Steady state distributions and stationary proabilities

Tags: markov-process

Whats the difference between steady state distributions, long run probabilities and  stationary distributions?

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Comment: This is somewhat of a vague question. I would consult your textbook and/or professor.